# How to exclude end marker in Javascript Regex replace

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Given the following HTML string...

```
<a href="mylink.com">Click here to approve</a>
```

I need to find and replace the text 'Click here to approve' so that the HTML string looks like this...

```
<a href="mylink.com"><font color="green">Click here to approve</font></a>
```

I'm using the following Javascript code to accomplish this.  Note that 'myHTML' is actually a much longer HTML string; I'm just including the pertinent section here.

```
var myHTML = '<a href="mylink.com">Click here to approve</a>';

//Change the color of the 'Approve' link to green
var approvalRegexPattern = /Click here to approve[\s\S]*?<\/a>/;
var approvalResultStr = approvalRegexPattern.exec(myHTML);
myHTML = myHTML.replace(/Click here to approve[\s\S]*?<\/a>/, '<font color="green">' + approvalResultStr + '<\/font>');
```

This mostly works, but the regex match ends up including the trailing 'a' tag so I end up with the closing 'font' tag outside of the 'a' tag instead of inside.

```
<a><font color="green">Click here to approve</a></font>
```

How can I adjust my regex pattern to match using the trailing 'a' tag but exclude it from the returned string so that my replace doesn't include it?

Comment: I'd suggest putting your HTML string in a detached container element and use the default DOM techniques to change the content of the anchor tag. Would probably be more stable than fiddling around with regexp.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  Unfortunately, it's not quite this simple. The HTML I'm working with is part of an outbound email communication that I need to manipulate on the fly, not part of a webpage that I can adjust using CSS or DOM manipulation.

Comment: But you tagged with "javascript", so you are using node.js here? If so, there are libs to simulate the DOM like JSDOM and others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your string is really only that, you just need:

```js
var myHTML = '<a href="mylink.com">Click here to approve</a>';
myHTML = myHTML.replace(/(Click here to approve[^<]*)(<\/a>)/, '<font color="green">$1</font>$2');
console.log(myHTML);
```

Comment: This one is technically correct, but doesn't give me the full flexibility I need.  The string I'm working with may have innerHTML that's slightly different from time to time so I can't limit it to just the exact 'Click here to approve' string.  I need to get everything starting with 'Click here to approve' all the way to the end 'a' tag.

Comment: This is perfect.  I figured there was a way to do this in one line but couldn't get the regex just right.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can split up what you are matching using parantheses '()', this means that the result string is now an array with element 0 being the entire match and each subsequent element being each set of parantheses you specified. For an example using your code see below:

```
var myHTML = '<a href="mylink.com">Click here to approve</a>';

//Change the color of the 'Approve' link to green
var approvalRegexPattern = /(Click here to approve[\s\S]*?)(<\/a>)/;
var approvalResultStr = approvalRegexPattern.exec(myHTML);
myHTML = myHTML.replace(/Click here to approve[\s\S]*?<\/a>/, '<font color="green">' + approvalResultStr[1] + '<\/font>' + approvalResultStr[2]);
```

Output:

```
<a href="mylink.com"><font color="green">Click here to approve</font></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code perhaps it helps you.

```
var myHTML = '<a href="mylink.com">Click here to approve</a>';

//Change the color of the 'Approve' link to green
var approvalRegexPattern = /Click here to approve[\s\S]*?/;
var approvalResultStr = approvalRegexPattern.exec(myHTML);
myHTML = myHTML.replace(/Click here to approve[\s\S]*?<\/a>/, '<font color="green">' + approvalResultStr + '<\/font></a>');
```

Comment: This one is technically correct, but doesn't give me the full flexibility I need.  The string I'm working with may have innerHTML that's slightly different from time to time so I can't limit it to just the exact 'Click here to approve' string.  I need to get everything starting with 'Click here to approve' all the way to the end 'a' tag.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question asks for a Regex fix, but I wonder if the Regex is a requirement, or just something you chose as 'the way to go'.

The reason is that there are IMHO better ways of achieving the same, using just plain CSS.

I will show three ways below: selection by attribute value, by id, and by CSS class name. Please have a look and see if it solves your problem easier or better than your original approach.

```css
a[href="mylink.com"] {
  /* selection by attribute value */
  color: green
}

#someId {
  /* selection by id */
  color: red
}

.makeItPurple {
  /* selection by class name */
  color: purple
}
```

```html
<a href="mylink.com">Click here to approve</a>
<br>
<a id="someId" href="otherlink.com">Click here to approve</a>
<br>
<a class="makeItPurple" href="yetanotherlink.com">Click here to approve</a>
<br>
```

Comment: Thanks for this Peter.  Unfortunately, it's not quite this simple.  The HTML I'm working with is part of an outbound email communication that I need to manipulate on the fly, not part of a webpage that I can adjust using CSS or DOM manipulation.